# how to enable my customers to add custom domains to link to personal page on my SaaS

Tags: php, symfony

I am building a system that allows customers to have their own webpage, Ex: System Domain: https://exampledomain.com

Right now all I did is for the customer to have their account as this: https://exampledomain.com/customername

I need the customer to be able to have his own custom domain completely pointed to the created webpage on the system. Ex: https://exampledomain.com/customername => https://customerdomain.com

I need to know how can I achieve this. Technology stack: OS: Ubuntu Webserver: Apache Programming language: php8 Framework: Symfony 6 DB: MySql

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a few ways to achieve this depending on your required design. The main thing is to use the *host* parameter on the route to determine what you would like to load, like templates, db's etc.